# Using Direction service in combination with Autocomplete service in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, maps

I have trouble setting my little application which uses the Google maps API 3.

In detail: I want to use two features:

1. Direction service: In order to calculate the route between two points and
2. Autocomplete feature in the textboxes that hold the source and destination points.

I have figured out that those two, need different script includes from google:

- [Autocomplete](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places)
- [Direction Service](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false)

If I add both in my `<head>` section, I get this warning:

> Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this
>   page. This may cause unexpected errors.

How can I combine those two javascript functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

When you take a look at both links to load the Google Maps API, you can see that they are very similar. What happens with the "libraries" parameter is that it loads additional scripts along with the default script. So basically what happens when you load both links, is that the default script is loaded twice and produces this error.

To combine the two, you just have to load only https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places.